# How to get a property of an IEnumerable<object> value

Tags: c#, object, properties

I have a getter and setter property named ValueIn, where an `IEnumerable<object>` is reached in.
The value contains all properties from IKontoDisplayModel filled with data. I want to extract the property "Nummer" from IKontoDisplayModel. How can I get this value? I always get this error:

`(value as IKontoDisplayModel).Nummer = '(value as IKontoDisplayModel).Nummer' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'`:

[image]

Comment: When creating question can you please copy and paste the code and not link a screenshot, makes it easier for people to copy and paste code around to test it, rather tahn having to type it themselves

Comment: Why is it an `IEnumerable<object>`? What does `value contains all properties from IKontoDisplayModel filled with data` mean? Why isn't the property a more appropriate data type, like just a `IKontoDisplayModel`? Is reflection involved somehow? What _does_ `value` contain in the setter? Is it an `IEnumerable<IKontoDisplayModel>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `value` is of type `IEnumerable<object>`, you try to change the type to `IKontoDisplayModel` which is never going to succeed. Since it looks like you are trying to gather all the numbers you could do:

`var nummern = value.Select(x => (x as IKontoDisplayModel).Nummer);`

But this might still generate a NullReference because some objects might not be of the specified type. You could filter the value IEnumerable by using the `OfType` extension method:

`var nummern = value.OfType<IKontoDisplayModel>().Select(x => x.Nummer);`

Which will only take the numbers of objects that are actually `IKontoDisplayModel`

Comment: _"never going to succeed"_ - well, `IKontoDisplayModel` could inherit from `IEnumerable<object>`, but apart from that this is the most sensible answer here.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems to me `IKontoDisplayModel` is a single object and you have an `IEnumerable` of `IKontoDisplayModel`. So you want to get one of them and then call `Number`. And by one of them I mean `FirstOrDefault()`,`LastOrDefault()` etc

Comment: Thats right, but when I do this:                 var nummern = (value as IKontoDisplayModel).Nummer.FirstOrDefault();
I get System.NullReferenceException

Comment: You want to go for (value.FirstOrDefault() as IKontoDisplayModel).Nummer

Comment: And that still can throw a NullReferenceException (`FirstOrDefault()` can return `null` or something that isn't a `IKontoDisplayModel`), so when you call `.Nummer` on that, it will still throw.

Comment: FirstOrDefault() would return null if IEnumerable is empty. So do you have anything in value

Comment: And also, if you read their (image of their) code, you'll see they're actually trying to join all `Nummer` properties into a single string, so no, they don't want to get one of them, but all of them.

Comment: I chose not to answer because the question is unclear. I commented on your answer because it is incomplete.

Comment: Great sir. Have a nice day. I wish I could complete it

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't understand why don't you use your `interface` instead of a generic `object`

2) You are passing an IEnumerable of it so you must do `value.FirstOrDefault()?.Number`

Comment: 1) Because of devexpress multiselection